# Visualize function calls with Graphviz for Windows programs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, profiling, graphviz

I came across this fascinating article *(on reddit)*: [Visualize function calls with Graphviz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-graphvis/?S_TACT=105AGX52&S_CMP=cn-a-l)

It explains how one could use: a GNU compiler toolchain, the Addr2line utility, custom glue code, and Graphviz to create visualization for your function calls.

I would really like to implement this in my code, except the issue is that my code is windows based. And I am using Microsoft c++ compiler.

The article explains about using GCC provided profiling functions for entry and exit:

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter( void *func_address, void *call_site )
                                __attribute__ ((no_instrument_function));

void __cyg_profile_func_exit ( void *func_address, void *call_site )
                                __attribute__ ((no_instrument_function));
```

Are there any such profiling functions for entry and exit provided by Microsoft c++ compiler?
That was the first issue.

The second issue is that I couldn't find any [Addr2line utility](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/addr2line1.html) for windows environment.  Basically it tells you filename, function name and line number of the memory address. Is there any way I could do what Addr2line does?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/Gh` compiler option to hook function call entry and/or `/GH` to hook function call exit.

There's a good example on MSDN at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can then use the DIA (Debug Interface Access) SDK to get the name of the function that was entered.

There's an end-to-end example of this at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47532/A-Simple-Profiler-using-the-Visual-Studio-C-C-Comp).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2 has this feature built in for those with the Ultimate edition of Visual Studio. (Well, it's not Graphviz based but it is a function call graph)